# Run functions in order

Tags: jquery, html

I have two functions that conflict in timing. No errors are displayed, but the site clearly doesn't respect the order of the functions. How can I have them safely run in tandem?

Code:

```
///////////////////////////// FADE IN ALL CONTENT

$(window).load(function() {
    $("#site-loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#site-container").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});

///////////////////////////// SKROLLR/MEDIACHECK

mediaCheck({
    media: '(max-width: 1024px)',
    entry: function() {
        skrollr.init().destroy();
    }, // END MOBILE MEDIACHECK
    exit: function() {
        var s = skrollr.init({
            // beforerender: function(data) {
            //     return data.direction == 'down';
            // },
            render: function(data) {
                //Log the current scroll position.
                console.log(data.curTop);
            },
            // smoothScroll: false,
            forceHeight: false,
            constants: {
                screen: function() {
                    return $(window).height();
                }
            }
        });
        $(function() {
            skrollr.get().refresh();
        });
    }
}); //END DESKTOP MEDIACHECK
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: You've got a bunch of functions there. Which two are you talking about? What is the symptom suggesting they're "clearly" being run "out of order"? What "order" would that be?

Comment: Im trying to first load the window.load function then the mediacheck function in the order that they appear. the mediacheck wraps another function that controls scroll-based animations on the page. However, because of the conflict, this function isn't working.

Comment: I'm beginning to realize that this may be occurring because the primary function is being run on window.load. Therefore it has to wait for the other to fire... Since the site container is set to `display:none`, the skrollr function isn't finding the elements it wants to animate. So I suppose the question is, is there a way to fire the mediacheck/skrollr function after the window.load function, in the same document?

Comment: Yes -- I've detailed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).load(function() { /*...*/ });` sets up a callback to that function that will be fired when the window's `load` event fires. That doesn't happen until very late in the page load process, after not only the HTML and all scripts and CSS files are loaded but also all images. Most of the time, `load` is the wrong thing to reach for.

The call to `mediaCheck` happens once the `load` callback has been set up (long before that callback is called).

If you want to call `mediaCheck` only *after* the code in the callback has been run, you have two choices:

1. Add a second `load` handler:

   ```
   $(window).load(function() {
       mediaCheck(/*...*/);
   });
   ```

   jQuery ensures that it fires event callbacks in the order they were attached.
2. Move the `mediaCheck` call *into* your existing `load` handler.

**More likely**, though, what you want to do is remove the `load` handler (unless waiting for all images really is a goal), move your `script` tags to the very end of the HTML (just before the closing `</body>` tag), and then just put the two bits of code one after another:

```
$("#site-loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#site-container").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
mediaCheck(/*...*/);
```

If you don't control where you put the `script` tags, you could use jQuery's `ready` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#site-loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#site-container").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
    mediaCheck(/*...*/);
});
```

Comment: I need the window.load function because that function shows a loader before the site is faded in... I inserted the mediacheck/skrollr functions into the window.load. It still doesn;t work but I believe this is definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#site-loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#site-container").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var s = skrollr.init({
                beforerender: function(data) {
                    return data.direction == 'down';
                },
                render: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.curTop);
                },
                smoothScroll: false,
                forceHeight: false,
                constants: {
                    screen: function() {
                        return $(window).height();
                    }
                }
            });
            $(function() {
                skrollr.get().refresh();
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
            skrollr.init().destroy(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Had to use a setTimeout.